# Why does Perl's DBI complain about "Fetch attempted on unopen cursor"?

Tags: sql, perl, informix, dbi, dirtyread

Here is my script:

```
$db_handle=DBI->connect("$dbstr", "", "",
{RaiseError => 0, AutoCommit => 0, PrintError => 1}) 
|| die "Connect error: $DBI::errstr" ;
$result=$db_handle->selectrow_array("set isolation to dirty read");
```

Note: `$dbstr` is a valid database name.

I am not a database programmer. What am I doing wrong which is causing the Perl script fail saying:

> DBD::Informix::db selectrow_array failed: SQL: -400: Fetch attempted on unopen cursor.

If I write a simple script to connect to database `$dbstr` and display the table contents it works fine but the above code does not work.

Comment: Please note that there are documented places to seek support for DBD::Informix (this isn't one of them, but it didn't exist when the last release of DBD::Informix was created).  Please note, even more importantly, that there is a *LOT* of version information that is needed to answer more complex questions, including the version of: Perl, DBI, DBD::Informix, ESQL/C (or CSDK), IDS (or other Informix DBMS), platform, and sometimes even the compiler.  These requirements are laid out in the documentation with the source.  There's even a script provided to gather most of it - InformixTechSupport.

Answer (score 3):

The `selectrow_array` method is intended for use with statements that return result sets.  The SET ISOLATION statement is not such a statement - it will fail.

Whether error -400 is the best possible error is slightly debatable - sometime I'll take a look and see whether anything can be done.  However, IIRC, the `selectrow_array` method is provided by DBI rather than DBD::Informix, so DBI builds it from lower-level primitives. Consequently, those primitives cannot provide the validation that the higher-level function could provide because they have to work separately too.

The correct way to write that code is:

```
$db_handle->do("set isolation mode to dirty read");
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no results for you to fetch from the statement you are executing:

```
set isolation to dirty read
```

so `selectrow_array()` is the wrong method to call.  Use [$dbh->do(...)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#do) instead:

```
$db_handle->do('set isolation to dirty read');
```

Here's a longer explanation of the -400 error:

> -400 Fetch attempted on unopen cursor.
>
> This FETCH statement names a cursor that has never been opened or has
> been closed. Review the program logic, and check that it will open the
> cursor before this point and not accidentally close it. Unless a cursor
> is declared WITH HOLD, it is automatically closed by a COMMIT WORK or
> ROLLBACK WORK statement.

As Jonathan points out, this may not be the clearest error, but it does make some sense once you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation for [DBD::Informix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::Informix), especially the "CONNECTING_TO_A_DATABASE" section. The minimum required code to connect to an Informix database seems to be:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Informix:$database");
```

Thus, you will have to provide more than just the name of the database.

Comment: The question said the connection was working - and therefore they did provide more than just the database name.  The x-ref to the DBD::Informix documentation is still useful, though.

Answer (score 1):

`set isolation to dirty read` is not a query, it is a statement.  Only queries go in `selectrow_array`.  You need `do`:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbi = "dbi:Informix:dbname";

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    $dbi,
    "",
    "",
    {
        RaiseError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 0,
        PrintError => 1,
        ChopBlanks => 1,
    }
) or die "Connect error: $DBI::errstr";

my $result = $dbh->do("set isolation to dirty read");

$dbh->disconnect;
```